# Why in some cases my icons disappear from the panel?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, panel

The code shown here is essentially what I am using to load the icons contained in the path of my addon. It is not the first time that I use this method, and it has never bothered me until now. However, in this case it seems that this also blocks the load of `bpy.utils.previews` of other addons so nothing will be loaded anymore, neither icons, nor personalized previews.

If I open a new project, the icons will be shown, but not always, in some cases I try to start Blender as Administrator, it seems to solve it but after a while the the icons are gone. System console is empty too.

```
import bpy,os

class MY_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):

    bl_label = "My panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "My category"

    def draw(self, context):

        ico = my_icon["icon"]

        layout = self.layout

        row =layout.row()
        row.label(text='My text',icon_value = ico['my_png_image_1.png'].icon_id)
        row.label(text='My text',icon_value = ico['my_png_image_2.png'].icon_id)

my_icon={}

classes = (MY_PT_Panel,
           #etc..
           )

def register():

    import bpy.utils.previews

    iconUtils = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    my_icon["icon"] = iconUtils
    iconsDir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"Icons") 
    for ico in os.listdir(iconsDir):             
        iconUtils.load(ico, os.path.join(iconsDir,ico), 'IMAGE')

    for cls in classes:       
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():

    for cls in reversed(classes):       
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

    for ico in my_icon.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(ico)
    my_icon.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The problem seems related to the mode of `Scene.render.engine`
When I open the project and use `'BLENDER_WORKBENCH'` the problem appears while opening the project in another render mode, all the icons are loaded correctly.

Any idea why this happens? I don't understand whether that's my fault or a bug...? *All icons are 32x32px, Blender 2.81, Win 10*

Comment: There's currently an open ticket [T74405](https://developer.blender.org/T74405) about this.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Yes, it seems to be a real bug, I am trying to get around the problem, but I am noticing that it seems impossible, since if they are loaded while viewing render 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH' these will remain loaded but not displayed